# Cannot send Function to Pyro

Tags: python, pyro

I am able to send math.sqrt over a Pyro connection however I cannot send a function that I have defined myself over a Pyro connection.

When I do, I get an Pickle Function Error.

Both the receiving module and the sending module have the function defined.

```
Pyro.core.initClient()
    connection = Pyro.core.getProxyForURI("PYRONAME://HelloWOlrd")

print connection.makeRequest(my_function)
```

And in my receiving side:

```
def makeRequest(self, function):
    return function(9)
```

Again, if I send a math.sqrt function over the connection, it prints out 3 which is expected, though If I try to send over a function I made, it gives me a pickle error:

cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup **builtin**.function failed

Again both the receieving module and the sending module have the function defined in their namescapes.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pickle class method, there is an enhancement request about it http://bugs.python.org/issue9276

[See there](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) for what objects can be picked and modify your code appropriate.

Comment: my function is def function(x): x**2

Comment: im using pyro 3.x, i heard that there was something like mobile code in Pyro 4? will it work with my situation